# Conflict between Modules Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The two modules below always run in a loop.
I want the second module for verification that a record was created after the first module runs, since all the user sees is the question, but not the result.

First module detects when new row is added to a table and asks if you want to export data to another worksheet:

```
Sub NewDatabaseEntry() 

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rspn As VbMsgBoxResult

rspn = MsgBox("Do you want to create a project? If you did not add a new row, click No", vbYesNo)
If rspn = vbNo Then Exit Sub       
        Range("MasterTemplate").Copy
        Sheets("Database").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

FindProjectName 'A macro that literally finds the name of the project...
'FindRow
End Sub
```

This module then looks at the row number on the destination worksheet and then copies that row number value to a predefined range.

```
Sub FindRow()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheets("Projects").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim foundRng As Range
    For Each rng In Sheets("Projects").Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
        Set foundRng = Sheets("Database").Range("C:C").Find(rng, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not foundRng Is Nothing Then
            rng.Offset(0, -1) = foundRng.Row
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The only way `FindRow` works is when I place it in the `ThisWorkbook~ Excel Object.
If I place it anywhere else, it gets into a loop with the NewDatabaseEntry module where it keeps asking you if you`want to create a new project.`
I would've liked for the user to know that the entry was created without having to close out of the workbook and then reopening it, just to verify what row number their record was placed on.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried fully qualifying the Workbook name in the second module? For example, `Sheets("Projects")` to `Workbooks("MyWorkbook").Sheets("Projects")`

Comment: @JosephSerido It caused a script out of range error when I tried your suggestion.

Comment: that's "subscript", i.e. the index supplied doesn't exist in the collection. Likely "MyWorkbook" isn't it and you mean to work with `ThisWorkbook` instead, rather than whatever workbook is currently active (unqualified `Sheets` implicitly refers to `ActiveWorkbook`).

Comment: What is calling `NewDatabaseEntry`? Is it a worksheet event? If so, you should turn off events until you finished your data manipulation in the second module.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Still doesn't work. Changed to `LastRow = Workbooks("ThisWorkbook").Sheets("Projects")...`

Comment: @JosephSerido If that doesn't run, there is no new row to be found.

Comment: Drop the `Workbooks(...)` part - if the `Projects` sheet exists at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook`, then give that `Projects` sheet a *code name* (change its `(Name)` property in the *properties* toolwindow (F4)), and then refer to it by its code name - e.g. `ProjectsSheet.Cells.Find(...)` - there's never a good reason to dereference a worksheet from `ThisWorkbook` through the `Workheets` (or worse, `Sheets`) collection. FWIW what I meant was `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects")`, not `Workbooks("ThisWorkbook")...`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Okay so I changed to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects"),,,` and it still runs in a loop until I click No.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that this gets stuck in an infinite loop to ask if they want to create a new project, I believe that the reason is because you have a `Worksheet_Change` event (or similar) that fires off when you add a value to the `Projects` worksheet.

The problem comes in when you have your `FindProject` manipulating data on the same worksheet that your `Worksheet_Change` event is looking for.

So what I believe you should do is turn off events until `FindProject` is done (by the way, I would recommend changing `FindProject` to something else because it does more than just "find a project").

```
Sub FindRow()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' ADDED THIS
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheets("Projects").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim foundRng As Range
    For Each rng In Sheets("Projects").Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
        Set foundRng = Sheets("Database").Range("C:C").Find(rng, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not foundRng Is Nothing Then
            rng.Offset(0, -1) = foundRng.Row
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.EnableEvents = True ' ADDED THIS
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```